# Is it necessary to purchase items to complete a set in The Greedy Cave?

Tags: android, greedy-cave

I want to know if it is possible to complete a set only with dropped items. Or if it is necessary to buy the pieces from the Town Lady?

Comment: Do you mean The Greedy Cave android game? I can't find any Greed Is Cave game anywhere

Comment: Yes The Greedy Cave android, my mistake.

Comment: I do reference a non-common sets for be more especific